# Capistrano deployment issue

Tags: windows, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano

I'm trying to get a Capistrano deployment script working, in my deploy file i have the following...

```
set :application, "example.com"
role :app, "root@12.34.56.789"
role :web, "root@12.34.56.789"
role :db,  "root@12.34.56.789", :primary => true

set :user, "root"
set :deploy_to, "/example/www/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 10

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Tell Passenger to restart the app."
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Symlink shared configs and folders on each release."
  task :symlink_shared do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/assets #{release_path}/public/assets"
  end

  desc "Sync the public/assets directory."
  task :assets do
    system "rsync -vr --exclude='.DS_Store' public/assets #{user}@#{application}:#{shared_path}/"
  end
end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_shared'
```

Also i have a github location and scm variable in the deploy file.  When I run `cap deploy` it starts off ok, asks for a username/password for github private repo, i enter that, its fine.  Then after that succeeds and pulls the code correctly I get the folllowing...

> executing "if [ -d /example/www/example.com/shared/cached-copy ];
>   then cd /example/www/example.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q
>   origin && git fetch --tags -q origin  && git reset -q --hard
>   93e3432103327f29a9e66fa2755562bfe9bc4412 && git clean -q -d -x -f;
>   else git clone -q https://github.com/example/example.git
>   /example/www/social u.com/shared/cached-copy && cd
>   /example/www/example.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b
>   deploy 93e3432103327f29a9e66fa2755562bfe9bc4412; fi"
>       servers: ["12.34.56.789"] Password:

So it asks for a password. I'm guessing this is for ssh. I enter the password for the root user, but then it fails displaying this...

```
    [12.34.56.789] executing command
 ** [12.34.56.789 :: err] Username:
```

I tried also not entering a password at all and I get the following....

> Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed
>   (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)

The catch is I am entering the right ssh password... I can ssh in fine using putty.   Btw I am running cap deploy on my local windows pc, and the remote box is a linux box.  Of course my location is not 12.34.56.78 but you get the point.  Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using the SSH url for GitHub, not the https one.

Comment: This got rid of the first password check, which is nice, but the second one which is mentioned in the question is still displaying for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve this by changing the user to not the root user.

Comment: I'll accept your answer for the effort + it helped get rid of the first password check, thanks :)